# StackPanel Transition Event

Tags: vb.net, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro

How can I call StackPanel to do its transition by a button click

Like when you search in the Metro(Start) Menu in Windows 8

I have tried

```
Panel1.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible
```

But it just changes the visible property and doesn't animate its entrance

Comment: It's a **panel** (not a *pannel* - one `n` is quite enough!)

Comment: I named my stack panel pannel1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at Windows Runtime transitions. In your case you would need [AddDeleteThemeTransition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.adddeletethemetransition.aspx) (from MSDN: "Provides the animated transition behavior for when controls add or delete children of a panel")